# Ubuntu 22.04 Random Crashes

Tags: 22.04

I need help understanding why my server keeps crashing randomly. I have looked many posts but with my limited knowledge I am unable to figure out the root cause of these crashes.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 headless with around 60 ish docker containers (Media/Apps/Websites/ etc). I have copied below few commands and outputs from a similar posts. if anything else is needed please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Please see the Logs here
https://pastebin.com/iGJdEFqT

As requested, My hardware specs are,

```
Lenovo TS140 Server
Processor:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1226 v3 @ 3.30GHz, 4 cores
RAM: 32 GB ECC RAM
GPU: Nvidia GEFORCE 1080 (Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: 11.4)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 (Linux 5.15.0-67-generic on x86_64)
Boot Drive: SSD (1TB)
Storage: 6TB NAS Drive
```

Thanks for looking.

I checked the /var/crash folder but it is empty

**Update 28/09/2023**

Still facing this issue but unable to get to bottom of this issue. Appreciate help with this issue. I have collected some logs using linux probe here https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=0e08685628

Thank you in advance

**Update 10/10/23
Today it's happening repeatedly.
Additional Logs from Ubuntu's system-info tool.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2mJfV2xFvF/

Can someone help diagnose this issue.
If there are any tools to diagnose such a issue please let me know.
Thank you

Comment: Please give your hardware specs.

Comment: Check for .crash files in /var/crash.

Comment: The posted logs are limited to grepping sensor output. They simply say that your crashes do not appear to be due to overheating.

Comment: Check "dmesg | grep panic"